# How to perform Callout and DML operation simultaneously?

Tags: apex, dml, callout

I'm facing a issue while doing a callout. I have tried from my side, but unable to wave it out.

1) Create a custom setting with name – FolderDetails .   //Done 
2) Have the custom settings store Object name and FolderID.  //Done
3)Create a method which takes the object type  and check in custom setting if the object type is existing , if existing then return true and create only subfolder taking the existing folder id as parent id for subfolder else create the Object type folder .

I have created a method createFirstFolder() which will create a folder in BOX server and will generate FolderID. I’m able to get the objecttype and folderID. And inserting into the custom settings.

Once Custom Settings updated, I’m calling a second method createSecondFolder().

But I’m getting the error message i.e.

> You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before
>   calling out issue workaround in salesforce

I know that you can'nt do the DMl operaion before callout.

Anyone can please guide me with another approach.

```
//Create my first Folder
    public PageReference createFirstFolder(){
             String objecttype = IdVar.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();
             System.debug('objecttype  :'+objecttype);
             APIReqRespWrapperRudra.BoxFolder boxFolderDetails=new APIReqRespWrapperRudra.BoxFolder();
             APIReqRespWrapperRudra.BoxFolder createBox=new APIReqRespWrapperRudra.BoxFolder();
             APIReqRespWrapperRudra.cls_parent  parentBox=new APIReqRespWrapperRudra.cls_parent();
             parentBox.id = '0';
             createBox.name=objecttype;
             createBox.parent=parentBox;
             boxFolderDetails= BoxIntegrationUtilities_Folder.createFolderInBox(createBox,'4yO2bWC19KUPeFdPNi36BAWRyjwfdLVj');
             System.debug('Folder ID : '+boxFolderDetails.id);
             System.debug('Folder Name : '+boxFolderDetails.name);
             UpdateCustomSettings(boxFolderDetails.name,boxFolderDetails.id); //Update custom settings with objecttype name and folderid
             createSecondFolder(boxFolderDetails.id,boxFolderDetails.name,objecttype); //It will call to another method to create a Inner folder within the folder just created.
             return null;
          }

private void UpdateCustomSettings(String ObjectName, String folderid){
        System.debug('++'+ObjectName);
        System.debug('++'+folderid);
        FolderDetails__c myCustomObject = new FolderDetails__c (Name = ObjectName, FolderId__c = folderid);
        insert myCustomObject ; 
        System.debug('!!!'+myCustomObject);  
     } 

public PageReference createSecondFolder(String folderId,String foldername, String objecttype){
         //String objecttype = IdVar.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName();
         System.debug('objecttype  :'+objecttype);
         List<FolderDetails__c> mcs = FolderDetails__c.getall().values();
         System.debug('MCS Size :'+mcs.size());
         for(Integer i=0;i<mcs.size();i++){
             if(objecttype == mcs[i].Name){
                 APIReqRespWrapperRudra.BoxFolder boxFolderDetails=new APIReqRespWrapperRudra.BoxFolder();
                 APIReqRespWrapperRudra.BoxFolder createBox=new APIReqRespWrapperRudra.BoxFolder();
                 APIReqRespWrapperRudra.cls_parent  parentBox=new APIReqRespWrapperRudra.cls_parent();
                 parentBox.id = folderId;
                 createBox.name=foldername + +' '+ System.Now() +'-';
                 createBox.parent=parentBox;


                 boxFolderDetails= BoxIntegrationUtilities_Folder.createFolderInBox(createBox,'4yO2bWC19KUPeFdPNi36BAWRyjwfdLVj');
                 System.debug('Folder ID : '+boxFolderDetails.id);
                 System.debug('Folder Name : '+boxFolderDetails.name);
                 return null;
              }              
         }

        return null;
```

Comment: Can you do `createSecondFolder` asynchronously? Marking it `@future` could solve your problem.

Comment: @MikeChale: I have used @future(callout=true) on createSecondFolder method. I'm not facing the error message that I was getting, but functionallity that I've written in my future method (To create a inner sub-folder) is not implementing on Box server, though in debug log I'm able to see that a new sub-folder is creted.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you will be able to solve that issue in an interactive context. You might have to use something like Batch Apex or Future methods to get around it. I have had a similar issue with Mixed DML and overcame it using Batch Apex.

So, firstly, I created a simple interface

```
public interface IAction 
{
    void process(BatchJob job);
}
```

Then, I created a couple of work classes to do the work for each type of action:

```
public class FolderCreator implements IAction
{
   public void process( BatchJob job )
   {
        // inject some state here and do the business
   }
}

public class CustomSettingUpdater implements IAction
   public void process( BatchJob job )
   {
        // inject some state here and do the business
   }
}
```

Then, in your start method of your Batch Apex, build up a list of IActions, for example

```
List<IAction> actions = new List<IAction>();
actions.add( new FolderCreator() );
actions.add( new CustomSettingsUpdater() );
```

Then, set your batch size to 1 and iterate over the actions thus isolating each action from one another, e.g..

```
for( IAction action : (List<IAction>)scope )
{
    action.process(job);
}
```

Not ideal having to use Batch Apex when really I didn't want to but it worked for me.

Comment: @future call can not be used in Apex Batch.